# Find nested array elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is my schema:

```
Appliance = new Schema({
    appliance_name: {type:String},
    appliance_id: {type:String},
    appliance_description: {type:String},
    keywords: [{ type: String}],
    appliance_type: { type: String},
    appliance_status: { light: { write_state: Number, read_state: Number },
                    fan: {write_state: Number, read_state: Number, write_speed: Number, read_speed: Number}
    }

});

Room= new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required:true},
    device_auth_code: {type: String},

    alt_name: {type:String},
    keywords: [{type: String}],
    appliance: [Appliance]
});

Home = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String},
    administrator: {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},

    users: [{ 
        _id: {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        email: {type: String},
        name: { type: String},
        status: { type: Number}
    }],
    rooms: [Room]


});
```

And here is the typical home.

```
 "type": true,
  "code": "GET_SUCCESS",
  "homes": {
    "_id": "58760ff6045e332b81449b42",
    "description": "",
    "administrator": "586df1e06485de5fc48b72a5",
    "name": "CM",
    "__v": 9,
    "rooms": [

      {
        "name": "RK",
        "alt_name": "RKa",
        "_id": "58775437234451346ce3d967",
        "appliance": [
          {
            "_id": "5877546f234451346ce3d968",
            "appliance_type": "Light",
            "appliance_name": "TubeLights",
            "keywords": []
          }
        ],
        "keywords": []
      }
    ],
    "users": []
  }
}
```

`Home` has nested array of rooms and each room has nested array of appliances.

`Home.findOne({'room.appliance._id': appliance_id})` would return the whole document. The `$` operator wouldn't work I would have to imagine.

Is it possible to receive that particular appliance or the whole document with that particular room and appliance only being returned?

How do I find a particular appliance and return that appliance?

Answer (score 0):

Here you've used [**mongoose subdocs**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) architecture in your home schema definition. So you could retrieve any particular room:

```
Home.findById(home_id, function(err, home){
  var room = home.rooms.id(room_id);
  res.json(room)
});
```

or a particular appliance:

```
Home.findById(home_id, function(err, home){
  var room = home.rooms.id(room_id);
  var appliance = room.appliance.id(appliance_id);
  res.json(appliance)
});
```